# Strip <p> from <blockquote> or something better?

Tags: php, functions, loop, the-content, wp-autop

Looking for some help on something that has me really contemplating not using blockquotes for the moment!

I have this code:

```
<?php
    $show_after_p = 1; $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
    if(substr_count($content, '<p>') > $show_after_p) {
        $contents = explode('<p>', $content); $p_count = 1;
        foreach($contents as $content) {
            $content = str_replace('</p>', '', $content);
            echo wpautop($content);
            if($p_count == $show_after_p) { get_template_part('_templates/box'); } $p_count++;
        }
    }
?>
```

The reason for the wpautop is to fix a short code in the content, and the way that inserting the box in before the first `<p>` rather than after.
Anyway, since the box is addded before the first `<p>` tag, in a blockquote, it inserts in-between:

```
<blockquote>
    <!-- The inserted box -->
    <p>The quote</p>
</blockquote>
```

So I'm looking for a way to strip the `<p>` from the `<blockquote>` (I realise it's not semantically correct, but the internet will have to heal with it!) OR something better..

Also I've added the `functions` tag in case someone from there could turn this into a function since I do have more than one post type this would apply to :]

Comment: Would it not be better to fix the problem shortcode instead of writing hacky code to work-around whatever that issue is?

Comment: This bug is like 8 years old and they haven't solved this yet: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/3833

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating HTML with regular expressions is not a good idea. I suggest you use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
// input
$html = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());

$dom = new \DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$blockquotes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
foreach($blockquotes as $blockquote){
  foreach($blockquote->childNodes as $e){
    if($e->nodeName === 'p'){
      // create a text node with the contents of the <p>
      $blockquote->insertBefore($dom->createTextNode($e->textContent), $e);

      // remove <p>
      $blockquote->removeChild($e);
    }
  }
} 

// remove doctype
$dom->removeChild($dom->firstChild);            
$dom->replaceChild($dom->firstChild->firstChild->firstChild, $dom->firstChild);  

print $dom->saveHtml();
```

Comment: Two items: 1. Where would I put this? 2. No way to do it with WP?

Comment: In your template file, where you want your blockquote?

Comment: But the blockquote is apart of the_content

Comment: Just replace the code you have above with this

Comment: And I just realised I only have 5.3.16 -,-

Comment: updated to work with lower versions

Comment: As much as I appreciate your help I've gone another route (which was my backup all along) - a `[blockquote][/blockquote]` shortcode.

Comment: Well that's the best solution. I didn't think you have control over the blockquote markup. You didn't mention that in the Q so I asummed you didn't. Oviously you don't need any parsing and replacing in this case. Just build the HTML as you want

Comment: Sorry, yeah I assumed 'cause it was coming from `the_content()` rather than markup.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a simple preg_replace, but you have to remove spaces around P in this example

$result = preg_replace('< p [^>]*>(?:\s+|(?: )+|(?:)+)*', '', $content);

If you will not use any tags inside blockquote, maube you can use  `strip_tags($content);`  to remove all html tags

Comment: At line do you suggest this to be added?

Comment: sorry man, the comment split some characters, the code is this
$result = preg_replace('<p[^>]*>(?:\s+|(?:&nbsp;)+|(?:<br\s*/?>)+)*</p>', '', $content);

Comment: You have to change the '<p[ and </p>, the first one is the beginner tag and the last '</p>'  I think you have to delete, sorry, I'm not an expert in this things